# I want to add gif to Discord Ticket Bot's message

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
{
    "embeds": {
        "openTicket": {
            "title": "Open a support ticket",
            "description": "Click on the button to start opening a ticket",
            "footer": { 
                "text": "test"
            }
        },
        "ticketOpened": {
            "title": "Ticket CATEGORYNAME",
            "description": "A staff will reply you as soon as possible!",
            "footer": {
                "text": "test"
            }
        },
        "ticketClosed": {
            "title": "Ticket closed",
            "description": "test"
        },
        "ticketClosedDM": {
            "title": "Ticket closed",
            "description": "test",
            "footer": {
                "text": "test"
            }
```

I tried to do it this way, but it didn't happen

"img": "imgurl"`

Comment: What was the URL you were using? Also why not use the `EmbedBuilder` class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add

```
thumbnail: {
    url: 'url of gif',
},
```

underneath the description. If that is not working try

```
image: {
        url: 'url to gif',
    },
```

undeneath it.